# Add class in select. Laravel 4

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

Hi :) I Have problem with form. I can't add a class 'form-control'.

```
        <p>
        {{ Form::label('id_category', 'Wybierz typ noclegu') }}
        </p><p>
        {{ Form::select('id_category', $categories, array('class'=>'form-control')) }}
    </p>
```

**array('class'=>'form-control')** 
Latavel it omits this class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the third argument to `Form::select` are actually the *selected options*. You need to pass HTML attributes as forth argument:

```
{{ Form::select('id_category', $categories, null, array('class'=>'form-control')) }}
```